# JQuery sliding/scrolling issue with Doctype

Tags: jquery, doctype

This has been asked already but the answer didnt solve my problem.

so I was wondering if you could help me with the issue im facing. When the doctype is specified, the Jquery code I am using no longer works. the code is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.slideto.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#menuHome").click(
                function()
                {
                    $("#home").slideto(
                    { 
                        slide_duration: 1000
                    });
                }); 

                $("#menuService").click(
                function()
                {
                    $("#service").slideto(
                    { 
                        slide_duration: 1000
                    });
                }); 

                $("#menuStudy").click(
                function()
                {
                    $("#study").slideto(
                    { 
                        slide_duration: 1000
                    });
                }); 
                $("#menuBlog").click(
                function()
                {
                    $("#blog").slideto(
                    { 
                        slide_duration: 1000
                    });
                }); 

                $("#menuContact").click(
                function()
                {
                    $("#contact").slideto(
                    { 
                        slide_duration: 1000
                    });
                }); 
                $("#buttonBackup").click(
                function()
                {
                    $("#home").slideto(
                    { 
                        slide_duration: 1000
                    });
                }); 
                $("#content1Button").click(
                function()
                {
                    $("#service").slideto(
                    { 
                        slide_duration: 1000
                    });
                }); 
                $("#footerButton2").click(
                function()
                {
                    $("#study").slideto(
                    { 
                        slide_duration: 1000
                    });
                });
                $("#footerButton3").click(
                function()
                {
                    $("#blog").slideto(
                    { 
                        slide_duration: 1000
                    });
                }); 
                $("#footerButton4").click(
                function()
                {
                    $("#contact").slideto(
                    { 
                        slide_duration: 1000
                    });
                });
            }); 



        </script>
```

Any help would be awesome, im trying to get this to work for a project im doing and ive only been learning HTML, CSS and JQuery the last 2 weeks, so please excuse any shizzness.

thanks

:-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you posted is not the whole page, so I'm just wondering if you are aware of the fact that your javascript stuff, as well as css and other includes should go into the `<head>` element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.slideto.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // JS code
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- HTML goes here -->
</body>
```

Also, whenever there's something wrong with your page, try making it a habit to always check the validity of your markup at the W3C validator site: http://validator.w3.org/ . If the markup is valid, your problem likely lies in javascript code.

**UPDATE:**

After some thought, one thing comes to mind. XHTML is **case sensitive!** Which means that all your jQuery selectors need to match the casing on your ID's and class names. HTML (without the x) is NOT case sensitive so `$("#Test")` and `$("#test")` are the same, but in XHTML they are completely different. What was likely happening is that without specifying the doctype, browser was falling back to HTML, so you didn't have to pay attention to casing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies, yep was already in the head tags, validating only came up with errors such as alt not defined, which is fine as this sort of thing I will sort out later on. 
I had that strict doc type initially, only changed it when testing to try and fix the issue, but still to no avail :-(